# На добавляется прозрачность водяного знака в Codeignither

Tags: php, codeigniter

Добрый день! добавляю на изображения водяной знак, средствами стандартной библиотеки codeightniher. [Ссылка на описание библиотеки.](http://code-igniter.ru/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html)

Добавляется все хорошо, но почему то не устанавливается значение прозрачности.

```
$config['source_image'] = $uploadfile;
$config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
$config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'images/stamp.png';
$config['wm_opacity']   = 50;
$config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
$config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
$config['padding'] = 20;

$this->image_lib->initialize($config); 

$this->image_lib->watermark();
```

`$config['wm_opacity']  = 50;` не работает. Почему?

Comment: Может быть `$config['wm_opacity']` попробовать в метод `$this->image_lib->watermark()` передать. Пробовали?

Comment: Ну как вариант накладывать уже полупрозрачный `png`

Comment: @korytoff ну да , придеться сделать Png полупрозрачную